# frames to video - Image processing in windows 8 (WinRT only)

Tags: windows, image-processing, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

Is there a way to process frames from a stream(or image file or video file) and save the frames in encoded video file. There are options for saving frame to encoded image file but no such option for saving to video file using **Windows.Graphics.Imaging** namespace.

In **mediaCapture.StartRecordToStreamAsync** i can use **StartRecordToStorageFileAsync** to save stream from camera of video file to another video file. But there is no way to save frame by frame. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [MediaCapture](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Media-Capture-Sample-adf87622) sample shows how to write a media foundation transform to do image processing on each frame.  I suspect you can modify the MFT to save each sample frame to a queue and then write the images from the queue asyncronously.

Comment: Thanks Larry! I have read the sample code!Its Exactly what I needed ... I have few more questions; 
**MediaCapture** class can only get stream from physical devices. 
My algorithm Flow is somewhat like this;
(1)open a video file or picture file (2) assign it to a (MediaCapture)stream (3) process the stream (4) Write the stream to video file using **StartRecordtoStorageFileAsync(parameters)**. So far I am unable to assign a video/picture object to a stream so that i can write it to a video file after processing.